# Combining functions in bash

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

I have written two functions into my `~/.bash_aliases` file; one returns the current working folder (everything after the last `/` in the directory path), and one sets the terminal tab:

```
function set-location { printf "\e]2;$1\a"; }
function get-location {
    local location=${PWD##*/}
    echo "$location"
}
```

Say I am in directory `james/foo/bar`. Combining the two functions, I expect the terminal window to be set to `bar`. However, I cannot work out how to combine them effectively. I have tried the following to no avail, though I am just guessing what would work at this point:

```
set-location get-location # terminal title: get-location
set-location $get-location # terminal title: -location
set-location ${get-location} # terminal title: location
set-location "${get-location}" # terminal title: location
get-location | set-location # terminal title: Terminal
```

How do I combine these two functions in a single line, so that I can set the location to be the result of `get-location`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use command substitution

```
set-location "$(get-location)"
```